# Hbase multiple range scans?

Tags: hbase

I have a table with millions of rows and I need to be able to select rows that contain a certain prefix.. there could be a few hundred+ prefixes that I would like to scan for. Each of these prefixes affect maybe 10 rows at maximum. In my experience range scans have always been much fasters than filters, and so I was hoping there would be a way to do a scan of multiple ranges rather than adding a PrefixFilter for each. Is there any way to do this in hbase, or at least a better alternative to PrefixFilters?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for **MultiTableInputFormat**. It allows us to feed data from  multiple scanners on a single table.

**Usage example:**

```
Scan scan1 = new Scan(); 
scan1.setStartRow(start1); 
scan1.setStopRow(end1); 
Scan scan2 = new Scan(); 
scan2.setStartRow(start2); 
scan2.setStopRow(end2); 
MultiTableInputCollection mtic = new MultiTableInputCollection(); 
mtic.Add(tableName1, scan1); 
mtic.Add(tableName2, scan2); 
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(mtic, TestTableMapper.class,   Text.class, IntWritable.class, job1);
```

This is the **[API](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/MultiTableInputFormat.html)** and this is the associated **[ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3996)**.

Comment: Is there any way to do this to just return the results? Ideally I would like to generate a ResultScanner that would have all Results from the specified row ranges.